# Interpreting a JSON structure in my c# example

Tags: c#, json

I have this kind of json structure:

```
      {
       "Root": {
           "data": [
               {
                   "CardName": "card1",
                   "functions": [
                       {
                           "State": "OPEN",
               "State": "INHERENT"
                       }
                   ]
               },
               {
                   "CardName": "card2",
                   "functions": [
                       {
                           "State": "CLOSED",
               "State": "INHERENT"
                       }
                   ]
               }
           ]
       }
   }
```

And my C# classes are :

```
    [DataContract]
public class Card
{
    [DataMember(Name = "CardName")]
    public string CardName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "functions")]
    public List<Function> Functions { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Function
{

    [DataMember(Name = "State")]
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to parse that structure in order to get a list of cards, and each card containing a list of functions.

At this moment i am trying this:

```
        string content = string.Empty;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("json"))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                content += line;
            }
        }

   List<Card> dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Card>(content);
```

but i only get a list of nulls. Can you please tell me where the problem is ?

Comment: You could try the other way around too: create a Card, serialise it to JSON and see what the output is?

Comment: Why are you using dynamic? - The result is on a known type (Article), therefore you can write Article or var.

Comment: Your definition of the Article class is missing above.

Comment: ok, indeed that should be Card. i will modify it now. And, i would expect a list of cards, is that possible ? Any method available ? I didn't find one.

Comment: basically you are missing root object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By pasting the JSON in Visual Studio (Edit > Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes), it tells me the classes for your data should look like this.

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Root Root { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public Datum[] data { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public string CardName { get; set; }
    public Function[] functions { get; set; }
}

public class Function
{
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

from http://json2csharp.com/

```
public class Function
{
    public string State { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public string CardName { get; set; }
    public List<Function> functions { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Root Root { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

please changes your jsona as below and try

```
   "Root": {
    "data": [{
        "CardName": "card1",
        "functions": [{
            "State": "OPEN"
        }, {
            "State": "INHERENT"
        }]
    }, {
        "CardName": "card2",
        "functions": [{
            "State": "CLOSED"
        }, {
            "State": "INHERENT"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the missing class is:

```
public class Article
{
    public List<Card> Root { get; set; }
}
```

The JSON has a mistake in it, it should be:

```
{
   "Root": [
           {
               "CardName": "card1",
               "functions": [
                   {
                       "State": "OPEN",
                   },

                   {
                       "State": "INHERENT"
                   }
               ]
           },
           {
               "CardName": "card2",
               "functions": [
                   {
                       "State": "CLOSED"
                   },
                   {
                       "State": "INHERENT"
                   }
               ]
           }
       ]
```

Notice that the functions should each be in a {} and the root class should contain a list of cards.

Alternatively, you could deserialize as List and then skip the wrapping "Root".

Answer (score 1):

There were many issues with the code. I have fixed those in below code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Threading;
using System.Xml;
using ConsoleDemo.Controller;
using ConsoleDemo.Model;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;


namespace ConsoleDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = @"{""Root"": {""data"": [{""CardName"": ""card1"",""functions"": [{""State"": ""OPEN""},{""State"": ""INHERENT""}]},{""CardName"": ""card2"",""functions"": [{""State"": ""CLOSED""},{""State"": ""INHERENT""}]}]}";
            RootClass dynObj = JsonHelper.JsonDeserialize<RootClass>(data); //Get the object
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class RootClass
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "Root")]
        public Data Root { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Data
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "data")]
        public List<Card> data { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Card
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "CardName")]
        public string CardName { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "functions")]
        public List<Function> Functions { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Function
    {

        [DataMember(Name = "State")]
        public string State { get; set; }
    }

    public class JsonHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// JSON Serialization
        /// </summary>
        public static string JsonSerializer<T>(T t)
        {
            var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            ser.WriteObject(ms, t);
            var jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            ms.Close();
            return jsonString;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// JSON Deserialization
        /// </summary>
        public static T JsonDeserialize<T>(string jsonString)
        {
            var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
            var obj = (T)ser.ReadObject(ms);
            return obj;
        }
    }

}
```